# Set bash variable so that it can't be unset

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to set an environment variable for all users via `/etc/profile` that the users can't override or unset. I'm pretty sure this is possible, but I'm having trouble locating the relevant documentation for the `set` and/or `export` shell built-ins. If this is indeed possible, how might it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`readonly`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/readonly).

```
readonly FOO='bar'
```

They cannot be changed and also can't be unset. From the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> ```
> readonly [-aAf] [-p] [name[=value]] …
> ```
>
> Mark each name as readonly. The values of these names may not be changed by subsequent assignment. If the `-f` option is supplied, each name refers to a shell function. The `-a` option means each name refers to an indexed array variable; the `-A` option means each name refers to an associative array variable. If both options are supplied, `-A` takes precedence.
>
> If no name arguments are given, or if the `-p` option is supplied, a list of all readonly names is printed. The other options may be used to restrict the output to a subset of the set of readonly names.
>
> The `-p` option causes output to be displayed in a format that may be reused as input. If a variable name is followed by `=value`, the value of the variable is set to `value`. The return status is zero unless an invalid option is supplied, one of the name arguments is not a valid shell variable or function name, or the `-f` option is supplied with a name that is not a shell function.

Comment: Ah, right, thank you. Knew it was in there somewhere.

Comment: I thought that was the answer, too, but I just tried that, and also exported the variable. I could not unset the variable in the parent shell, but I could unset it in the child shell. (Using Bash 4.1.7, `VAR=foo`, `readonly VAR`, `export VAR`, `xterm`, then in the xterm, `echo $VAR` displays value, `unset VAR` no message, `echo $VAR` displays blank.

Comment: @garyjohn Huh, weird. Works for me with child shells launched in Bash. Although I don't have xterm, so I cannot try that.

Comment: I think it's known not to work with child shells (or at least isn't _guaranteed_ to work). In my case, the solution is good enough as is.